# create a custom view programmatically then animate it

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, transform, uianimation

I'm creating a custom view programmatically, which is working fine, then I'm trying to animate the view.  For some strange reason the view is animating at all, I'm not sure why.  Here is the code:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))

    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    customView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    customView.layer.borderWidth = 8
    customView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

    self.view.addSubview(customView)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 4, animations: {

      customView.transform.translatedBy(x: 40, y: 60)
      customView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi/2)
      customView.transform.scaledBy(x: 0, y: 0.5)

    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you better call this animation block in viewDidAppear, with some delay.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var customView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
        customView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap)))

        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        customView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        customView.layer.borderWidth = 8
        customView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

        self.view.addSubview(customView)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 1, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
          self.customView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 0.5)
          self.customView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/2)
          self.customView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 40, y: 60)
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    func handleTap() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.customView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 0.5)
            self.customView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/2)
            self.customView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 40, y: 60)
        }, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Really helped me!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not correct. your view is not animating.

**Why?**

You are using a return function and your customView needs to catch the modified version like this.

```
customView.transform =  customView.transform.translatedBy(x: 40, y: 60)
```

So your code would be like this.

let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))

```
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    customView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    customView.layer.borderWidth = 8
    customView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

    self.view.addSubview(customView)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 4, animations: {

       customView.transform =  customView.transform.translatedBy(x: 40, y: 60)
       //customView.transform = customView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi/2)
       //customView.transform = customView.transform.scaledBy(x: 0, y: 0.5)

    })
```

There are lots of online resources how to group animation.Just google it.:)